# skip-secure-auth option not working with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export a mysql schema from remote server to local but geting the following error:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump  --skip-secure-auth -h  x.y.z.d -uatulya  -p'root'  t_tcadmin |mysql -u root -proot t_tcadmin`

`mysqldump: unknown option '--skip-secure-auth'`
`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Without the `--skip-secure-auth` it connects but  I get error `2049`.
So I want to use this option to skip secure auth but it is giving the above error. 
Could anyone suggest.
Thanks..

Comment: You can take a look to this response: 

Suppress warning messages using mysql from within Terminal, but password written in bash script
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written/20854048#20854048

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a pinch, dealing with an older server where updating the passwords to the newer method is not an option (say, MySQL Server v5.0.95) and attempting to migrate the data to a newer system - without modifying the fragile older system, you may need to temporarily downgrade your local mysql client to 5.5 for myasqldump to be able to talk to the older server.  As of 5.6 it is possible to use the MySQL client to connect to it - using --skip-secure-auth in the command, but mysqldump will not accept that flag.  And, in MySQL 5.7+ it is impossible to connect to a server that uses the older password storage method at all.